How to automatize this "justify" way?
After months of research I found (on stackexchange thanks to other user) a way to justify
the text (cut it at char 88, every line go \n after char 88)
join
s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g

When I run it manually works perfect (only insert some space cutting the words, but this is another problem). I have tried to automatize it, inserting in a "script"
#!/usr/bin/vim
'<,'>join
'<,'>s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g

or
#!/usr/bin/vim
%:join
%:s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g

But both failed if "called" in select mode with error e481
The question is: is possible to call a script or function in visual select mode (<>) ? I want to "include" the two commands :%join and :%s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g in one function or script to recall in "select visual mode" (shift+v).
The gif explain better (see the error in red)


Could you precise what you would like to achieve? Do you want to add a command in the command line to "justify" your script at startup? Do you want to define a Vim command to justify a buffer?

I want to "include" the two commands %:join and %:s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g in one function or script to recall in "select visual mode" (shift+v)

Why not :set textwidth=88 and v<motion>gq?

To "justify" your script when starting Vim you could do:
vim.sh:
vim -c %join -c %s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g $1

If you call vim.sh file.txt Vim will open the file.txt and execute the two command on the buffer:

%join
%s/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g

If you want to introduce a function that can justify a range you could do:
function! Justify() range
  execute a:firstline . ',' a:lastline . 'join'
  execute a:firstline . ',' a:lastline . 's/\v.{88}\zs/\r/g'
endfunction

To use it:

Select a range of line
Run: :'<,'>call Justify()

Remark the '<,'> part will automatically be inserted when you hit :
You can also introduce a mapping:
vnoremap J :call Justify()<CR>

Remark: To justify respecting the words I would do:
:set tw=88
:normal gggwG


Thanks but I need a way to do it in "select mode"

Thanks for the feedback. I have introduced a Vim function that operate on a the range of selected lines.

The function works really fine, thanks

Thanks for the feedback :-)

The problem is that :source only takes a range or a filename, not both. Your script already has '<,'> range markers in it, so you can select the lines of interest and do :<C-u>source script.vim.
You can also place arbitrary commands in a script (no #! line) and use -S to execute them at startup.

N.B. The current script will probably choke on the #! line.
